# Administrator being asked for admin password when running admin programs

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, administrator, active-directory, uac

I have a user that is part of the default 'Administrators' group and the default 'Domain Users' group. When the user tries running a program on Windows 8.1 Industry Pro that requires administrator priveledges, he gets asked for an administrator username and password, though he is already an admin. Entering the user's own details here does not work but entering the details of the default Administrator account does.

I've tried adding this user to the 'Domain Admins' group instead of the 'Administrators' group where the problem was solved, but the user could not use the Windows Server Manager Application (he received an 'Access Denied' error) and could not administer AD Users and Computers, both of which are necessary for my setup.

I'd like the user to not have to enter the admin details when running something requiring admin priveledges. Please can somebody tell me how to do this?

**Edit: I also thought of trying to delete the user from the 'Domain Users' group, although I am not sure if this would have any negative consequences (e.g. loss of access to computers/files.)**

---

P.S. The reason I posted here instead of on ServerFault is because I am running this on an experimental home network instead of on a business environment.

Comment: "Entering the user's own details here does not work but entering the details of the ." - Please complete this incomplete statement.  "I've tried adding this user to the 'Domain Admins' group instead of the 'Administrators' group" - You can do this with a user that is already in the group.  "I'd like the user to not have to enter the admin details when running something requiring admin priveledges. " - If you want this why are you esclating the permission on the process?

Comment: In reply to Ramhound - ""I've tried adding this user to the 'Domain Admins' group instead of the 'Administrators' group" - You can do this with a user that is already in the group." - I do not understand what you mean by 'You can do this with a user that is already in the group'. Also, I did not escalate the permissions on the process, these are just programs such as installers and settings which naturally required admin priveledges.

Comment: Update your question and delete the your comment.

Comment: **"I do not understand what you mean by 'You can do this with a user that is already in the group'."** - There is some user on your domain that is already a member of this group.  You should use that user to add another user to the Domain Administrator user group.  **"I did not escalate the permissions on the process, these are just programs such as installers and settings which naturally required admin priveledges."** - Same difference really.  There is no way around the UAC prompt in that case

Comment: **"Entering the user's own details here does not work but entering the details of the default Administrator account does."** - It sounds like you are not entering the domain when you attempt to authenticate the user, so your attempting to authenicate against a local user that doesn't exist, this the reason the built-in Administrator account does authenticate